# Dynamically trimming informational border off of FAA sectional raster charts?

Tags: raster, gdal, gdal-translate

I'm trying to write a script that can automatically use GDAL to crop the informational border from the FAA's published sectional charts (GeoTIFF) found **[here](http://aeronav.faa.gov/index.asp?xml=aeronav/applications/VFR/chartlist_sect)**:

I know that I can use `gdal_translate -projwin ulx uly brx bry` to crop it to a coordinate range, but I'm not sure where to get the values for the map area aside from by hand, or if there is possibly a better way to crop it.

Is the information necessary to crop the chart extractable from the files they provide?

Answer (score 6):

You will find the borders in degrees in the enclosed html file. gdalinfo can give you the same values, but these are the corners of the tif **including** the legend, not the map canvas you are interested in. Unfortunately, the map is in a lcc projection, and thus the borders do not follow the exact degree of latitude and longitude, and are not even rectangular.

So you have to create a cutline shapefile using QGIS manually. The shapefile should have  the same CRS as the tif file.

- Load the tif file into QGIS. I took Albuquerque North as reference. A custom CRS will be created
- Set the project CRS to that of the layer
- Create a new polygon shapefile, choosing the custom CRS from the first step
- Draw a polygon around the map content
- Adjust the corners by zooming in if necessary
- Use `Raster -> Extraction -> Clipper` to create a new tif file, with nodata set to 0, and the polygon shapefile as mask layer. The command line will look this way:

> ```
> gdalwarp -dstnodata 0 -q -cutline D:/Karten/shp/Länder/USA/AlbuqN_extent.shp -crop_to_cutline -of GTiff "D:\\Karten\\shp\\Länder\\USA\\Albuquerque 92 North.tif" D:/Karten/shp/Länder/USA/AlbuqN.tif
> ```

You have to do that once for every map, and can then use gdalwarp with that commandline indepently from QGIS for future downloads of the same map.

Comment: The FAA has changed the format to some degree of the downloads with the new format being available in March. Sample File is [Here](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/vfr/media/Seattle_SEC_86_NFN.zip)
Will this remove the need for the steps you describe in your answer or will it still be the same.

Comment: Quote from FAA Web Site: `Instead of using scanned chart images, the new d-VC is created directly from our digital files, resulting in a crisper and brighter image with improved georeferencing.`

Comment: I see no changes in format, so the steps will be the same.

Comment: Tried this, but get an error on the Clipper. Command is `gdalwarp -dstnodata 0 -q -cutline "C:/test.shp" -crop_to_cutline -of GTiff "C:/test.tif" "C:test cut.tif"` The Error is in `python/plugins\raster_transparency\rastertransparency.py" TypeError: QSpinBox.setMinimum(int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'long'` QGIS version: 2.1.0-Master Master, fa90fc9 - If I select create Output Alpha Band, then no error, but output is completely black.

Comment: Never Mind, it failed on the old format files, but worked fine on the new format mentioned above in my comments. Will just wait until they issue. Thanks.

Comment: The New format Files are now available at the [FAA](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/vfr/) Site

Comment: Still no changes on my workflow. I tested the Detroit map.